# Does Bootstrap add horizontal spacing to <img> by default? If so, is there a way to override this setting?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm designing a homepage in which I'm trying to display the same image 4 times in a single row (to make a kind of decorative banner). I have set each images' `width` to take up 25% of the screen. Theoretically, this means each image should take up a quarter and fit perfectly within a single row. However, I suspect Bootstrap is adding some kind of spacing between my images causing the 4th to spill over into the next one.

I have tried setting their `margin` to `0`, setting their `padding` to `0`, and setting their `border-style` to `none`. I figured setting the properties this way would override any defaults Bootstrap might place on the `<img>` tag, but this spacing does not seem to be going away. Additionally, checking the Developer Tools on my browser confirms that there is in fact no margin, padding, or border affecting my images. I'm not sure what else I can target to try and resolve this issue.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time in advance.

NOTE: I am not using Grid. I figured what I am attempting to do is simple enough to avoid having to use it.

```
<img class="back-banner" src="pictures/walyn-homo-erectus.jpg">
<img class="back-banner" src="pictures/walyn-homo-erectus.jpg">
<img class="back-banner" src="pictures/walyn-homo-erectus.jpg">
<img class="back-banner" src="pictures/walyn-homo-erectus.jpg">

.back-banner {
    width: 25%;
    opacity: .5;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: add your code which you are using in sample snippet.

Comment: this was the code i was using. although i was able to wrap the html with ```<div class="row no-gutter"></div>``` and it fixed the problem nicely. thanks again though!

Answer (score 1):

Image is inline element by default. This causes it to add some white space. You can transform it to block element by using `display: block`, but then you need to use `float: left` to make them appear in one row.

Even better is to use modern css like [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) by adding `display: flex` on wrapping element.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.

I was able to find another solution by wrapping my images inside ```<div class="row no-gutter"></div>```